# Need to change lowercase_underscore string to camelCase

Tags: java, case-sensitive

I Need to change String : **underbar + lowercase = uppercase**.(and the opposite)

```
my_name -> myName
```

Is there any library or something to help this out?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use the [`CaseFormat` class's `LOWER_UNDERSCORE`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.html#LOWER_UNDERSCORE) from google [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) :

```
CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, "my_name")
```

Comment: Guava really has everything :)

Comment: Note that this converts a camel-cased string to lowercase, e.g. `accountUsers` to `accountusers`, in which case it can be useful to use this only if necessary, e.g. the original string contains an underscore.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest a custom solution

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("_(.)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("my_name");
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1).toUpperCase());
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

output

```
myName
```

Comment: Why StringBuffer and not StringBuilder ?

Comment: Because Matcher.appendReplacement wants StringBuffer

Comment: thanks didnt feel like including Guava just for this

Comment: With this code, if you pass in MY_NAME, you will get MYNAME, instead of MyName.

Comment: @FlorinMarcus you could call `final String input = "MY_NAME"; final String output = input.substring(0,1) + input.substring(1).toLowerCase()` beforehand.

Answer (score 5):

[`CaseFormat`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#caseformat) is an utility class in Google Guava for converting between case conventions.

Comment: I fixed the link. Thanks @aristotll for the notification.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use StringTokenizer:

```
    String value = "id_app";
    StringTokenizer toekn = new StringTokenizer(value,"_");
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(toekn.nextToken());
    while (toekn.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String s = toekn.nextToken();
        str.append(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0))).append(s.substring(1));
    }
    System.out.println(str.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this code, I have verified it.

```
        String str = new String("my_name");

        for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++){
            if(str.charAt(i)=='_' && (int) str.charAt(i+1)>=97 && (int) str.charAt(i+1)<=122){
              str=str.replace(str.substring(i, i+2),""+(char)((int) str.charAt(i+1)-32));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s="My_name";
        int i=s.indexOf('_');       
        s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString(s.charAt(i+1)),Character.toString(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i+1))));
        s=s.replaceAll("_","");
```

Comment: A little explaination or reference wouldn't harm, usually asking these questions usually don't have the base yet to know everything you're doing and this would help.

Comment: If there are multiple occurences of the character you want to replace you should put this into a recursive method and instead of #`replaceAll(String, String)` use #`replaceFirst(String, String)`. The first parameter being the character to replace (at index `i`) concatenated with the character you want to capitalise (at index `i+1`), and the second parameter your capatalised char (as above)

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="srinivas";

s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString(s.charAt(0)), 
                 Character.toString(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0))));

//s Value is "Srinivas" now
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace lower case character following  underscore with uppercase using [appendReplacement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String))

> The appendReplacement and appendTail methods can be used in tandem in order to collect the result into an existing string buffer

```
    String text = "my_name_is";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([_][a-z])").matcher(text);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group().substring(1).toUpperCase());
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
```